# angular - the animation effect fails when loading the component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I want to make a `opacity` effect when the page-component is loaded, but I found that it must be set a `setTimeout()` in order to operate successfully.
Is there a better way?

For example:

component:

```
@Component({
  selector : 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id="component" [ngClass]="{show: block}">
    content
  </div>
  `
})
export class FaderComponent implements OnInit {
  block: boolean = false
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit() {

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.block = true;
    },100)

  }
}
```

scss:

```
#component {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  &.show{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This framework has an animation module: https://angular.io/guide/animations read this Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-animation) for reference to add animation on component load.